# Page redirection not working for mvc in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Data is successfully retrieved from ajax call. 
In ajax success i need to redirect to '/Account/Index', but redirection not working in ajax success.
Is there any alternative for window.location.href?

```
$.ajax({        
            url: "/Register/Register",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(RegisterMember),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (s) {
                console.log(s);
                //LoadprojectsGrid();
                // End For


                if (s.MessageCode == 1) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    window.location.href = '/Account/Index';
                }
                else if (s.MessageCode == 2) {
                    $('.cssload-loader').remove();
                    $('#overlay').remove();
                    $.growl.error({ message: s.Message });

                }
                 else
                 {
                    $('.cssload-loader').remove();
                    $('#overlay').remove();
                    $.growl.error({ message: s.Message });

                }


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
                $('.cssload-loader').remove();
                $('#overlay').remove();
            }
        });
```

Comment: `window.location.href='newUrl'` should work. Are you sure your if condition returns `true`?

Comment: yes condition return true

Comment: Acording to W3C: The window.location.href property returns the URL of the current page.

Comment: you can set a new url to that property for redirection. Have been using it for ages and never had a problem in any browsers!

Answer (score 1):

Without href:

window.location = '/Account/Index';

Comment: if you want, use assign method:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

Acording to some data I found it should be

```
window.location
```

and not

```
window.location.href
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using URL helper as following:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Account")';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove**

```
event.preventDefault();
```

And use

```
window.location = '/Account/Index'; as stated by @marcos
```